# Cancel image transform/transition when backface-visibility is hidden

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have a box which flips on click. There's also an image inside that zooms on hover, shown in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aJY34/2/).
The problem is the zoom transition on the image which is hidden is briefly displayed when I put the mouse out or back in.
[My attempt](http://jsfiddle.net/VhXvd/1/) to fix it:

```
#box.flip:hover img{
    -webkit-transform: none;
}
```

But this one resets the image before the flip transition is done which looks ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add z-index:

```
#box.flip .amount{
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
    z-index:999;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aJY34/3/